# Error:java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Tags: java

I have a javafx assignment of a program (like email) that sends messages between users and communicates based on their ip & port address.

However, when creating a user with ip & port number i always get the following error: **Error:java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind**. I tried endless port options, including ports that are not listed in my current processes, but it doesn't seem to solve it.

Is there a way to generate/find an available ip address & port number?

Comment: Under Windows, with `netstat -an` you can see which ports are in use.

Comment: First things to check would be to make sure that a previous instance of your process is not still running (task manager / `ps aux` / etc). Otherwise, you should include what ip/port you're attempting to bind to in your question.